# How to populate textbox value real time upon date start and end entry on a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Q: How can I populate a text box value (number of days) realtime based on a user entering start and stop dates within an mvc3/razor view?  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Either you would onblur, postback with Ajax and use server logic to fill the textbox value with number of days. Or, ideally, you would use jquery to do this so it is most responsive and realtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a jquery newbie (mainly biz layer SDE)...do you have any code examples using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#textbox1, #textbox2").change(function()
    {
    $.ajax(
        {url: '/controller/action',
        data: { date1: $("#textbox1").val(),date2: ("#textbox1").val()},
        success: function(data){
                 $("#days_textbox").val(data);
               }})
    });
```

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I'm a jquery/ajax newbie.  Q: do I have to include the server method as such and return a json result such as?:  [HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult action(string startdate, string enddate) {...}  or can I just return a string (public string action(string startdate, string endate) {...}  ???